# Altering an already altered form of Invite module

Tags: forms, redirection

Trying to learn how to override forms I've read the instructions on https://www.drupal.org/node/1975230 and see I need to identify the form itself. The form that I need to redirect is located on `user/1/invites/invite_by_email`, so looking at the HTML code of the form:

```
<form action="/user/1/invites/invite_by_email" method="post"
 id="invite-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

So taking its id `invite-form` I found its function in the `invite.admin.inc` file of Invite module at line http://cgit.drupalcode.org/invite/tree/includes/invite.admin.inc#n177:

```
function invite_form($form, &$form_state, $invite) {
  $form['#entity'] = $form_state['invite'] = $invite;

  $form['uid'] = array(
    '#type' => 'value',
    '#value' => $invite->uid,
  );

  field_attach_form('invite', $invite, $form, $form_state);

  $submit = array();
  if (!empty($form['#submit'])) {
    $submit += $form['#submit'];
  }

  $form['actions'] = array(
    '#weight' => 100,
  );

  $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save invite'),
    '#submit' => $submit + array('invite_form_submit'),
  );

  // Show Delete button if we edit invite.
  $invite_id = entity_id('invite', $invite);
  if (!empty($invite_id) && invite_access('edit', $invite)) {
    $form['actions']['delete'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Delete'),
      '#submit' => array('invite_form_submit_delete'),
    );
  }

  $form['#validate'][] = 'invite_form_validate';

  return $form;
}
```

Then there is another function invite_by_email_form_invite_form_alter() at http://cgit.drupalcode.org/invite/tree/modules/invite_by_email/invite_by_email.module#n283:

```
function invite_by_email_form_invite_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $invite = $form['#entity'];

  if (!empty($invite->type_details()->invite_sending_controller['invite_by_email'])) {
    $language_subject = $form['field_invitation_email_subject']['#language'];
    $invite_by_email_settings = isset($invite->type_details()->data['invite_by_email']) ? $invite->type_details()->data['invite_by_email'] : array('use_default' => TRUE);

    if ($invite_by_email_settings['use_default']) {
      $message_editable = variable_get('invite_message_editable', FALSE);
      $replace_tokens = variable_get('invite_default_replace_tokens', TRUE);

      // Override the default mail subject and body with the global defaults.
      $form['field_invitation_email_subject'][$language_subject][0]['value']['#default_value'] = variable_get('invite_default_mail_subject', '');
      $form['field_invitation_email_body'][$language_subject][0]['value']['#default_value'] = variable_get('invite_default_mail_body', '');
    }
    else {
      $message_editable = $invite_by_email_settings['message_editable'];
      $replace_tokens = isset($invite_by_email_settings['replace_tokens']) ? $invite_by_email_settings['replace_tokens'] : TRUE;
    }

    // Hide if message is not editable.
    if (!$message_editable) {
      $form['field_invitation_email_subject']['#type'] = 'hidden';
      $form['field_invitation_email_body']['#type'] = 'hidden';
    }
    else {
      // Add token help if enabled.
      if (module_exists('token') && $replace_tokens) {
        // Add tokens help.
        $form['token_help'] = array(
          '#title' => t('Replacement patterns'),
          '#type' => 'fieldset',
          '#collapsible' => TRUE,
          '#collapsed' => TRUE,
          '#weight' => $form['field_invitation_email_body']['#weight'] + 0.5,
        );

        $form['token_help']['help'] = array(
          '#markup' => theme('token_tree', array('token_types' => array('user', 'profile', 'invite'))),
        );
      }
    }

    $form['#validate'][] = 'invite_by_email_form_invite_form_validate';
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Send Invitation');
  }
}
```

and it looks like more the one I need to redirect.

However this function is already an `alter` function itself and I am confused how can I alter it. Can I alter another alter function? If not and if I need to work with the original invite_form function at http://cgit.drupalcode.org/invite/tree/includes/invite.admin.inc#n177, then do I need to copy invite_by_email_form_invite_form_alter() at whole as I don't want to change how it works - I only need to redirect it to another page (to user/1/invites/pending in fact) on form submit.

Bear with me if the question is too simple as I am just learning. I would appreciate if someone could give me a code to try.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually alter the alter, but you can create your own custom module that uses hook_form_alter plus a custom function to redirect upon form submittal.

Create a custom module. For this example, let's call it invite_redirect.

If you haven't created a custom module before, these instructions are fairly good but are missing a very important step:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/getting-started

The missing step is creating the .info file which is required. Name yours invite_redirect.info. It goes inside the sites/all/modules/custom/invite_redirect along with invite_redirect.module. All that absolutely has to be in the invite_redirect.info file is the following...

```
name = Invite Redirect
description = Redirects to custom location upon submittal of the invite_by_email form
core = 7.x
```

In the invite_redirect.module file, add this code...

```
<?php
function invite_redirect_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'form_invite') {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'invite_form_submit_handler';
  }
}

function invite_form_submit_handler(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'user/1/invites/pending';
}
```

I would enable this and see if it works (flush caches after enabling it). If it doesn't work, you may have to specify a weight for your custom module (so it gets the last word durring rendering). There are several methods for doing this described here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/howtos/how-to-update-a-modules-weight

I prefer the .install file method they discuss.

Hope this helps you.

Anne

Comment: Didn't test this as I've decided to offer a patch to the module's maintainers to address this issue https://www.drupal.org/node/2840914#comment-11851423 But based on your answer to my somehow similar question in the other thread I am pretty sure it works, therefore I am accepting your answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry Anne, but I really want to learn this. I've just used your code and it didn't work. Are you sure the check should be for 'form_invite_form_alter ' and not 'invite_by_email_form_invite_form_alter'?

Comment: Doh! You're right: the form id should be form_invite. I'm correcting my post in case someone else stumbles upon it. sorry about that.

Comment: Unfortunately, it always ends landing at individual invite page like https://domain.com/invite/73 and it does not redirect to user/1/invites/pending.

Comment: I suspect this is because of the relative weight of the modules attempting the hook_form_alter on this form. I would try one of the methods they discuss here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/howtos/how-to-update-a-modules-weight

Comment: Dear Anne, I've just ran the `drush sql-query "UPDATE system SET weight=999999 WHERE name = 'my-custom-module'";` and tried to invite again to land on individual invite page again. Besides I've put dpm() in the function which doesn't output anything. So I am afraid it is not about module weight - it simply doesn't trigger the way you suggested.